# What is the meaning of "@" above "def"?

Tags: python, django

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_mothods

@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def my_view(request):
    pass
```

There is a "@" in above example. But I could not figure out that.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: it's the [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators).

Comment: (Protip: I searched SO for `"@" [python]`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is used to `decorate` a function. This mechanism is called a `decorator`.

A decorator is a function that will modify the behavior of another function.

In your case, the `require_http_methods` decorator checks that the request is a GET or a POST method before calling the `my_view` function.

It's a very powerful mechanism and I do recommend to spend a little time for understanding it. You can start with this [tutorial](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/)

I hope it helps